# Handling common pop ups across the application java webdriver testng

Tags: java, webdriver, testng, popupwindow

I have a common pop up in my application that is basically a prompt for "Unsaved Changes with "Yes" and "No" buttons".

Problem is : I want to handle this from a common place in Automation Framework , I don want to handle this pop up in each and every test case.
Is there a way so that I can write a custom listener which can trigger as soon as this pop up appear on UI.

If not what should be the best approach in a automation framework to handle such pop ups those are common across the Application and not very predictable where they will appear.

I am using java and TestNG along with WebDriver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your popup would do you can register events with the following `interface WebDriverEventListener` referenced at http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html

Personally I like the approach of directly handling this with a custom error handler and recursive function calls.  It gives you more exact control...although it takes more programming to get it to work.  Either way within your event/exception handling you can put your custom code to handle the popup with an `driver.SwitchTo().Alert().accept()` or `driver.SwitchTo().Alert().dismiss()` or custom code to interact with your custom popup elements.

---

That being said since you have two options in your popup you will want to ensure that you do have some tests that address this directly otherwise you won't be testing all cases.  Maybe you could have a one line call to a function that handles the accept/reject of the popup and you just pass in a bool value whether it's accept or reject...